# Program to track in which drive it should be installed and keeping a track

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have an issue. Could not resolve it so posting it here. Actually when any installation goes on it will asked to the user in which drive we should install. So it installs there and keeps a track of where it got installed.

So in the same way i wish to ask the user by a C# program in which drive he wants to keep a file and later I should be able to track it.

I mean to Say suppose the user installs in C drive later he uninstalls it and installs in D drive. I wish to know in which drive it is being put not by searching but in any other way. Like a registry or so which i can check where it is and get the details from it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85t3c3hf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), if it's Windows only app, you've answered it by yourself :)

Other ways may include config files, embedding this information to executable, or setting up the web service that holds data about every installation. (one day this will be more simple way than registry...)

Answer (score 1):

do u want to install any windows application or just want to put some files into a directory. For first case u can use `Application.StartupPath`

[For more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath`.